# How to serve a Node/Express application from a Linux virtual machine running on VirtualBox?

Tags: express, server, virtualbox

I'm having problem trying to access a Node/Express application running on a Linux virtual machine. I've set the port forwarding up and it works fine. I can access the server running on Apache, but not on Node/Express.

This is the Node/Express application I'm trying to access from the host machine. Nothing especial there, but could my code be wrong?

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app);
const hostname= '127.0.0.1';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World')
})

server.listen(PORT, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${hostname}:${PORT}`);
})
```

It works fine on the guest machine, but I'd like to access it from the host. Bellow you can see images for reference. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. Shut down the Guest and install a "Bridged Adapter" in Setting -> Network. This will bring the Guest to the same subnet as the Host.
2. Start the Guest.
3. Add a rule to any firewall in the Guest for inbound traffic.
4. Access the Guest from the Host by IP. Example  `http://192.168.1.1:8080`

Comment: Thank you! I've tried what you suggested, but unfortunately it didn't work.  My Ubuntu firewall is set as the following:

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       192.168.1.1               
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)